# What does MySQL return to Java, on an entry error?

Tags: java, mysql

If I run an insert statement from Java to insert a value into a MySQL database, but the value is a duplicate where the column must be unique, how can I catch that in Java?

I'd ideally like a try/catch so that if it is a duplicate, it returns a message to the user. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this needs to be a constraint you set in your MySQL database. Otherwise, duplicate entries are allowed (minus of course primary keys and such).

If you don't want to do this approach, first prepare a SELECT statement. If this returns 0 results, you know that you have a unique insert value, otherwise throw an exception.

Comment: The DB already returns an error if you try to add a duplicate, I'm just not sure how to identify it in Java.

Comment: how are you executing your SQL statement? What java utility are you using?

Comment: you sure whatever you are using isnt throwing a SQLException? Did you try catching generic Exception?